# Java sound replaying via Clip and AudioInputStream is not working

Tags: java, ubuntu, wav, javasound

This is a slightly modified example from the Java Sound info page. https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javasound/info Unfortunately, it only plays the sound once but the intention is twice.

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.sound.sampled.*;

public class TestNoise {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File f = new File("/home/brian/drip.wav");
        AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(f);

        AudioFormat af = ais.getFormat();
        DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(Clip.class, af);
        Clip clip = (Clip)AudioSystem.getLine(info);

        clip.open(ais);
        clip.start();    // heard this
        Java.killTime(); 
        clip.start();    // NOT HEARD
        Java.killTime();
    }
}
```

**Edit: To understand the answer, see the link provided by Wanderlust or just do what it says in the comment below his answer.**

Comment: 1) Does the exact source shown in the [JavaSound info. page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/javasound/info) for playing a WAV work for you?  2) Does that exact source (except URL changed) fail for your test WAVs?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html).

Comment: @broiyan: why did I waste my free time working on your Swing validate question if you're just going to delete it? Duly noted for future reference.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For playing the clip for the second time you must call

```
clip.start();
clip.stop();
```

cause after the second call of clip.start(); it is trying to play the file from the place where [it stopped previously](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/Clip.html).

Comment: Thanks.  It needed a clip.setFramePosition(0); to make it replay properly.

Answer (score 0):

This wonderful API worked for me:

```
import javax.sound.sampled.*;
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;

/**
 * Handles playing, stopping, and looping of sounds for the game.
 *
 * @author Langdon Staab
 * @author Tyler Tomas
 */
public class Sound {
    Clip clip;

    @SuppressWarnings("CallToPrintStackTrace")
    public Sound(String filename) {
        try (InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream(filename)) {
            assert in != null;
            InputStream bufferedIn = new BufferedInputStream(in);
            try (AudioInputStream audioIn = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(bufferedIn)) {
                clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
                clip.open(audioIn);
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException("Sound: Malformed URL: \n" + e);
        } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException("Sound: Unsupported Audio File: \n" + e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException("Sound: Input/Output Error: \n" + e);
        } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException("Sound: Line Unavailable Exception Error: \n" + e);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // play, stop, loop the sound clip
    }

    public void play() {
        clip.setFramePosition(0);  // Must always rewind!
        clip.start();
    }

    public void loop() {
        clip.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);
    }

    public void stop() {
        clip.stop();
    }

    public boolean isPlaying() {
        //return false;
        return clip.getFrameLength() > clip.getFramePosition();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).